# Athena SQL Compounding Returns

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Can you provide an example of how you would compound the returns in below table using only athena sql?  Expected output is in rightmost column.

Compound Return = (1 + prior.day.compound.return) * (1 + current.day.return) - 1.

If day = 1 then compound return is daily return.

```
Day | Company | Daily Return | Compound Return (Expected Output)
----------------------------------------------
1   |A        |0.05          |0.05
2   |A        |0.33          |0.40
3   |A        |0.12          |0.56
1   |B        |0.21          |0.21
2   |B        |-0.05         |0.15
```

Comment: where is expected result source data?

Comment: Daily Returns column.  (1 + 0.05) * (1+0.33) - 1

Comment: see "window functions" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html  where you would use **lag()**  for prior day information

Comment: @Used_By_Already can you please share an example of how you would use the lag function in my example?

Answer (score 2):

Lag is a function that is used in conjunction with an `over clause`.

```
select Day , Company , DailyReturn
     , lag(DailyReturn,1) over(partition by Company order by day) as PriorDayReturn
from yourtable
```

In this example the prior day return is shown on each row, excpet when there is no prior return (per company) where the value will be NULL.

```
Day | Company | Daily Return | PriorDayReturn
----------------------------------------------
1   |A        |0.05          |NULL
2   |A        |0.33          |0.05
3   |A        |0.12          |0.33
1   |B        |0.21          |NULL
2   |B        |-0.05         |0.21
```

Please refer to (*your friend*) the documentation for details of `lag()` and  `over()`